double negation in prolog
Why in the below example the loves1 works (false as kate likes paul) while the loves does not work (true)?
We assume that love is true if it is mutual and exclusive.
likes(kate, tom).
likes(tom, kate).
likes(kate, paul).

friendship(X,Y):-
    likes(X,Y),
    likes(Y,X).

not_friendship(X,Y):-
    \+ friendship(X,Y).

loves(X,Y):-
    friendship(X,Y),
    (not_friendship((X,Z), Z\=Y), not_friendship((Y,W), W\=X)).


loves1(X, Y) :-
    friendship(X, Y), % X and Y like each other
    \+ ((likes(X, Z), Z \= Y); (likes(Y, W), W \= X)). % There are no others that X or Y like


there is a bit of confusion with parentheses in the body of loves/2

For \+ the Goal must be ground to be safe (which not_friendship does not guarantee) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729518/logical-negation-in-prolog

@brebs can you please elaborate in math logic how this is "not safe" and why? If you could put this into answer i'd accept.

This question is probably a duplicate of others. Just trying to find a definite answer to link to - probably https://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse45 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662868/why-is-prologs-failure-by-negation-not-considered-logical-negation
